# Random generate three integer values and check if they are unique

Tags: actionscript-3, random

First, I am generating random integer values to get some values to check.

```
var A1, B2, C3:int;
A1 = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
B2 = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
C3 = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
```

Then I want to check if all the variables are unique from each other.

```
if (!(A1 == B2 || A1 == C3 || B2 == C3)){
        unique = true;
}else{ // Not unique
}
```

If the variables are not unique to each other, I want to keep only the value for A1, and then change the two other variables B2 and C3 and then again check if they are unique.

```
}else{ // Not unique
            if (unique = false){
                do{
                    B2 = Math.random() * A1 + 1;
                    C3 = Math.random() * A1 + 1;

                    if (!(A1 == B2 || A1 == C3 || B2 == C3)){
                        unique = true;                  
                }while (unique = true)
    }
            trace("Not unique");
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot get three unique values, and any help on how I can solve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this actionscript or java? seems that java tag is invalid. Also while-loop tag seems irrelevant

Comment: @saberduck This is AS3, but I am tagging this with java since it is similar to AS3. I also want help with the logic and not only the semantic.

Comment: well, that's not really how tags should be used, this has no relevance to Java, otherwise you could also tag it C or any C-style syntax language. See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where instead of asking to resolve the problem at hand you should probably have started by explaining what you are trying to do and what's the best way to achieve it. Since you have been posting a few times already my guess is that you are trying to extract 3 unique int from a range of 0 to 100. If that's the case then you are trying to create a complex and inefficient way to do it which is interesting by itself but is far from the point. The solution is to simply generate an array of int from 0 to 100 and then extract 3 of them randomly. In that case they will always be unique and always from 0 to 100.

```
var intRange:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    intRange.push(i);
}
var index:int = Math.flor(Math.random() * intRange.length);
var a:int = intRange[index];
intRange.splice(index, 1);
index = Math.flor(Math.random() * intRange.length);
var b:int = intRange[index];
intRange.splice(index, 1);
index = Math.flor(Math.random() * intRange.length);
var c:int = intRange[index];
intRange.splice(index, 1);
//3 unique int from 0 to 100 range
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the wrong code here:

```
if (unique = false) { // must be: if (unique == false)
    do {
        ...
    } while (unique = true) // must be: while(unique == false)
}
```

also it can be reduced to

```
while(!unique) {
    ...
}
```

Also, there you are taking random from A1, not 100. Just too many errors. The proper code should be:

```
var a:int, b:int, c:int; // also, why would you call variables A1, B2, C3???
a = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
do {
    b = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
while(b == a);
do {
    c = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
} while(c == a || c == b);
// here you have unique
```

Now, the answer given by BotMaster is correct and robust but it involves filling an array and splicing it which is not always ok, especially if random range is significantly more than 100 and we need only three values from it.